# Shell command execution (sh -c) does not set variable?

Tags: bash, shell

When I execute `/bin/sh -c "X=1;echo $X;"` it prints empty line. What am I doing wrong? My platform is macOS if it matters...

Answer (score 1):

I think I have answer to my own question. It looks like variable is expanded before `sh -c` is run. So I should have written `/bin/sh -c "X=1; echo \$X;"`

Comment: Or use single quotes: `/bin/sh -c 'X=1; echo $X'`.